# Using beautifulsoup to obtain CGI info

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, cgi

I am a slight bit lost about where to go, thought you might be able to help. I am trying to scrape data automatically from the following search form

http://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/play_finder.cgi

To do so, I am running BeautifulSoup on a string matching the request url of interest like so:

```
url=http://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/play_finder.cgi?request=1&super_bowl=0&match=all&year_min=2015 &year_max=2015 &game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&quarter=1&tr_gtlt=lt&minutes=15&seconds=00&down=1&yg_gtlt=eq&yards=-5&is_first_down=-1&field_pos_min_field=team&field_pos_max_field=team&end_field_pos_min_field=team&end_field_pos_max_field=team&type=RUSH&is_complete=-1&is_turnover=-1&turnover_type=interception&turnover_type=fumble&is_scoring=-1&score_type=touchdown&score_type=field_goal&score_type=safety&is_sack=-1&include_kneels=-1&no_play=0&order_by=yards&more_options=1&rush_direction=LT&pass_location=DL&
BeautifulSoup(url)
```

I am certain that the string is correct, as I have plugged the string into a browser several times and seen the necessary table (here, the individual plays table with id="all_plays"), but when I run BeautifulSoup on url, it misses the mark:

<.html><.body><.p>http://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/play_finder.cgi?request=1&super_bowl=0&match=all&year_min=2015&year_max=2015&game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&quarter=1&tr_gtlt=lt&minutes=15&seconds=00&down=1&yg_gtlt=eq&yards=-5&is_first_down=-1&field_pos_min_field=team&field_pos_max_field=team&end_field_pos_min_field=team&end_field_pos_max_field=team&type=RUSH&is_complete=-1&is_turnover=-1&turnover_type=interception&turnover_type=fumble&is_scoring=-1&score_type=touchdown&score_type=field_goal&score_type=safety&is_sack=-1&include_kneels=-1&no_play=0&order_by=yards&more_options=1&rush_direction=LT&pass_location=DL<./p><./body><./html>

(I added periods in each html tag so that it wouldn't attempt to format the tags that BeautifulSoup attaches).

I am assuming this has to do with this being a request to a remote cgi, but I don't have any answers for that.

Is there a way that I can grab the table using beautifulsoup? Otherwise I would turn to selenium driver and maybe automate it that way, but that is a last option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are currently asking `BeautifulSoup` *to parse your URL as a string*. `BeautifulSoup` is an HTML parser, not the HTTP request library, it would make the request to the URL in this case.

Instead, use, for example, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package to make a request and parse the response with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/play_finder.cgi'

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.113 Safari/537.36"}
    session.get(url)

    response = session.get(url + "?request=1&super_bowl=0&match=all&year_min=2015 &year_max=2015 &game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&quarter=1&tr_gtlt=lt&minutes=15&seconds=00&down=1&yg_gtlt=eq&yards=-5&is_first_down=-1&field_pos_min_field=team&field_pos_max_field=team&end_field_pos_min_field=team&end_field_pos_max_field=team&type=RUSH&is_complete=-1&is_turnover=-1&turnover_type=interception&turnover_type=fumble&is_scoring=-1&score_type=touchdown&score_type=field_goal&score_type=safety&is_sack=-1&include_kneels=-1&no_play=0&order_by=yards&more_options=1&rush_direction=LT&pass_location=DL&")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    for row in soup.select("#div_down table tr")[1:]:
        print([cell.get_text() for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```

This prints the first "Down" table data rows:

```
['1', '100.0%']
```